# Python 3.6 ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I have the following in my code:

```
y.append(float(row[-1]))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'finish_pos'
```

I am relatively new to Python. Can anyone explain this or help me? Thanks

Comment: I strongly feel that you have a non numeric string like `a2.d3` this is not an convertable string

Comment: thanks. Is there a way I can check for this? I have many lines in my file.

Comment: you can use to check this link https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python-including-unicode/

Comment: thank you, I did indeed have a non numeric string.